# use MailCore 2 without github

Tags: github, mailcore2

I develop application in XCode which use MailCore 2 library.
Application works, everything is fine
But yesterday in my country github was blocked.
So, I can't build my application.
Logs:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dinhviethoa/tidy-html5.git/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan.git/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain 
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dinhviethoa/ctemplate/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
```

Why MailCore need github and what to do in this situation?

Comment: Did you update to the latest version of mailcore2?
It doesn't need github any more.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà thanks, I try this. In my version now I blocked access to Internet and start build. It's work.